# TikZ: How to remove unwanted lines within an element? (something like TRIM)

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following, i want only outer edges. I can use `fill=white` to remove unwanted circle portion. How to remove unwanted edges of rectangle?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
        \draw[fill=white] (0,1) rectangle (3,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When i have

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
        \draw[fill=white] (0,1) rectangle (3,2);
        \path[fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

the circle is not thick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual solution is to `\clip` a path, but in this case you can simply draw the `circle` after and use `fill=white` with `fill opacity=1`.  As you want only the outer edges you can "fill" in the rectangle afterwards making an adjustment for the width of the line:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
 
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
        \draw (0,1) rectangle (3,2);
        \draw [fill opacity=1, fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
        \draw [draw=none,fill=white, fill opacity=1] 
                ($(0,1)+(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle ($(3,2)-(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I do not want the circle portion also. I want only outer edges.

Comment: @sandu: See updated solution.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a one-liner:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
        \draw[fill=olive!30] (3,2) -- (0,2) arc (-270:25:2cm) -| (3,2) --cycle;        
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I may, a `clip` method

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\draw[fill=white] (0,1) rectangle (3,2);
\begin{scope}
\clip [] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm-0.5\pgflinewidth]; 
\fill[white]  (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```